# Openstack Folsom server detail JSON response cannot be unmarshalled

Tags: json, openstack, openstack-nova

> If you hit the api for getting the server details in Folsom, you would
>   notice the entity "addresses".
>
> The entity has a child element as list of network name. It seems
>   impossible to unmarshall the JSON response to Java object as the
>   response does not seem to follow a schema because the network name
>   will depend on the implementation. Is there a workaround or am I
>   getting something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like https://bugs.launchpad.net/nova/+bug/1084560 -- I'd go there and comment if you want to help get the bug fixed.